# Как ускорить COUNT запрос?

Tags: mysql

```
$res_region = db_query ("
  SELECT ".prefix."post_region.*,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM ".prefix."post_db
    WHERE ".prefix."post_db.region = ".prefix."post_region.name
  ) AS CountReviews
  FROM ".prefix."post_region
  WHERE name != ''
  ORDER by name ASC
");
```

Подскажите как можно ускорить запрос, генерация страницы занимает 34 секунды.
В базе 700 тысяч записей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Версия MySQL:   5.5.62

Comment: Если бы был explain этого запроса, было бы больше возможности разобраться

Comment: Если есть индексы `post_region (name)` и `post_db.region`, то единственной оставшейся точкой оптимизации является переход от связи по текстовому `name` к числовому коду.

Comment: покажите `create table` ваших таблиц; и попробуйте для начала избавиться от подзапроса переписав запрос на `join`. и какая версия `mysql`?

Comment: можно еще не подзапросом считать а на джйон переписать, приджойнить выборку `region,count()... group by region`, если по крайней мере число эти различных `region` относительно не велико

Answer (score 0):

Вы так и не показали `show create table` таблиц, поэтому попробую угадать, что там внутри.

На плане запроса видно, что подходящих индексов нет (`possible_keys = NULL`). Пора добавить. На оба поля по которым идёт объединение: `".prefix."post_db.region` и `".prefix."post_region.name`.

Только не надо добавлять в индекс всю строку целиком! `varchar(55)` это зло. Попробуйте для начала 5-10 первых байт. Если строки по большей части одинаковые в начале, то найдите ту границу, откуда идёт заметная разница и пусть индекс будет длиной до этой границы + чуть-чуть.

Кажется, что регионы вы уже вынесли в отдельную таблицу. Т.е. нормализовали это дело. В этом случае и объединять лучше по числовым ключам. У вас же наверняка есть первичный ключ в таблице регионов.

Само объединение (даже если оставить его по текстовым полям) лучше вынести из подзапроса переписав всё на `inner join .. group by`.